# Default argument for a multiple argument function only when no argument supplied

Tags: python, function, arguments

Let's consider a function that accepts multiple arguments as under:

```
def my_function(*args):
    my_list = []
    for _ in args:
        my_list.append(_)
    another_function(my_list)
```

Now, the issue that I face in my scenario is that: I need `my_list` to contain at least one value, any argument, but at least one.

A user can do `my_function(arg1)`, `my_fuynction(arg1,arg2)`, `my_function(arg1,arg2,arg3)` and so on. But if a user does `my_function()`, I need to provide a default argument (say arg1) to the function.

If I put an default argument, then the argument defaultarg will be compulsory and it has to be supplied with some value:

```
def my_function(defaultarg, *args):
    #function
```

If I put it as optional argument, then I will have to provide a default value to the argument:

```
def my_function(optionalarg = defaultvalue, *args):
    #function
```

Both these ways do not work for me as I can't make it compulsory and I can't give a default value for it.

How do I create this function so that if no arguments are passed, the function assumes one argument to have been passed?

As of now, I am handling this by putting a if...else in the function as under:

```
def my_function(*args):
    my_list = []
    if len(args) == 0:
        my_list.append('defaultarg')
    else:
        for _ in args:
            my_list.append(_)
    another_function(my_list)
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I want the function to be flexible to allow user to pass multiple arguments as well as allow it to be called without using any argument, in which case, a default result will be generated.

Comment: I think this question is ok, the "I can't give a default value for it" confused me a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't give a default value for it

I don't understand this part of your question. You are providing the default value `'defaultarg'` in your own solution?! My answer assumes that you can get the default value from somewhere.

Anyway, if you want to keep the `f(*args)` signature, you can check whether the `args` tuple is empty and supply a default value.

```
def my_function(*args):
     if not args:
         args = (default_value,)
     # more code
```

or

```
def my_function(*args):
     if not args:
         return my_function(default_value)
     # more code
```

You won't get around explicitly checking whether `args` is empty, but maybe you'll like one of these proposals better than your version.

edit:

You could also write a parameterized decorator.

```
def with_default_value(default_value):
    def with_default_value_decorator(f):
        def f_new(*args):
            if not args:
                return f(default_value)
            return f(*args)
        return f_new
    return with_default_value_decorator
```

Example:

```
@with_default_value('hi')
def my_print(*args):
    print(' '.join(args))
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_print('hello', 'world')
hello world
>>> my_print()
hi
```

Comment: Thanks. The decorator method is great.